# Menu Token - roles issue

Tags: routes, 7

I am using Menu Token to create a link to a customized profile edit page that uses the url "user/%uid/edit". I've set the title of the link to "My Account" and although it works for my (admin) account, for the other roles the title is "Edit" instead (the default Drupal tab name for the /user menu item) and futhermore it does not appear to be the active trail. My thinking is that it's something to do with permissions since it works in one role but I can't seem to figure this out. Any help?

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you say, is the title changing for different roles (like from "My Account" to "Edit")..

Comment: Precisely that!

Comment: are you sure that they are same links (i.e. pointing to the same URL). To check whether it is an issue menu tokens, you could try using [ME alias](http://drupal.org/project/me) and replacing `%uid` from your URL by `me`.

Comment: It's exactly the same link. When logged in as admin the title is what I've specified it to be, when not, it's Drupal's default "Edit".

Comment: i was not able to reproduce the problem on my Drupal 7 installation. can you please list out the modules you are using to achieve this?

Comment: Just the latest stable version of Menu Token. Did you create a link to "user/%uid/edit" and name it differently?

Answer (score 2):

I think I got the answer.. just check for the snapshot. It seems you were using the wrong value of token in menu path. Use `user/[user:uid]/edit` instead.

[image: snapshot]

Comment: sadly, no. I am using exactly that :(

Comment: try using `user/[current-user:uid]/edit`

Comment: same thing. i just went and overrode the title with code and fixed it that way. can't waste too much time on it.

Comment: ahh, ok. I'm not sure what caused the problem. I think you should report it as issue on [drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue); have a thread running there and see if it helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same problem using `user/[current-user:uid]/edit` and switched to `[current-user:edit-url]` which worked for me. The link title is now displaying as entered for all roles, not just admin.